# how to combine foreach uploading files

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload, uploading

i have an upload script with that i like to upload a couple of images to a directory.

i use this code:

```
$allowed_extension = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'tiff', 'gif');
$errors = array();
$output = array();

if(!empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){  

     foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $key => $array_value){

        if(!in_array(pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'][$key], PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $allowed_extension)){
                die("Die!");
        }
    }

    foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $key => $array_value){

       $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'][$key];
       $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'][$key];
       $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key];

       $file_extension = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
       $file_extension = strtolower($file_extension);

         if (!in_array($file_extension, $allowed_extension)){
        $errors[$file_name][] = "format $file_extension in image $file_name is not accepted";
        continue;
         }

         if ($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[$file_name][] = "maxsize of 2MB on $file_name has reached";
                    }

         if (count($errors) == 0){

        $dir = "a/b/c";

        if (is_dir($dir)){
            mkdir("a/b/c/tmp_images", 0755);
        }else{
            mkdir("a/b/c", 0755);
            mkdir("a/b/c/tmp_images", 0755);
        }

        $path = "a/b/c/tmp_images"; 
        $prifix = basename($file_name, "." . $file_extension);

        //var_dump ($prifix);

        $uploadfile = $path . "/" . $file_name;

        $x = 0;
        while (file_exists($uploadfile)){
               $x ++;
               $uploadfile = "{$path}/{$prifix}-{$x}.{$file_extension}";
            }

            if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $uploadfile)){
               $file_name = basename($uploadfile);
               $output [$file_name] = "OK";

            }else{

            $output[$file_name] = "Failure while Uploading!";
            $errors[$file_name][] = "Failure: Can't move uploaded pictures!";
            }//else...
         }//if(count($errors))...
    }//foreach($_FILES['image']['name']... 
}//if(!empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])...
```

the problem is that part:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){  

         foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $key => $array_value){

            if(!in_array(pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'][$key], PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $allowed_extension)){
                    die("Die!");
            }
        }
```

in case of uploading two different kind of file types it will cancel the upload. this is my first problem. in such a case i need to cancel the upload because this is for a file that i like to build after posting the form. so the user has no possibility to make any changes after he has post the form. let's have a look at the second part:

```
foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $key => $array_value){

           $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'][$key];
           $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'][$key];
           $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key];

           $file_extension = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
           $file_extension = strtolower($file_extension);

             if (!in_array($file_extension, $allowed_extension)){
            $errors[$file_name][] = "format $file_extension in image $file_name is not accepted";
            continue;
             }

             if ($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[$file_name][] = "maxsize of 2MB on $file_name has reached";
                        ...}
```

here it can be seen that it actually should be approached that an error message should have been displayed. if i leave the first foreach-part then i got the problem that in case of two different file types one file will be uploaded and for the other one the errormessage will be displayed.

so there should be a way to combine the first and the second foreach. if there is someone who could tell me the right way i really would appreciate. thanks a lot.

**UPDATE**

okay, sorry for my lateness. here my feedback: this code seems to have some problems in case of two different file types. it seems like

```
if (count($errors)>0){
   die ("...")
}
```

does not really count. in case of that it will get the error message:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to access a/b/c/tmp_images/abc.xls
```

but it will also do an upload for the image that has an allowed extension but this can't be successfull because of the wrong filetype of the other one, i guess. the problem is that this causes the insert query that is placed here:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, $fileDst)) {
            $output[$fileBase] = "OK";

            **$insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO table ( a, b, c) VALUES('".$a."','".$b."','".$c."')");{

            mkdir("a/b/c/d/e", 0755);
            rename("a/b/c/tmp_images", "a/b/c/d/e/tmp_images");

            $msg ="text abc.";                          

            $to = "xxx@xxx.xx";
            $subject = "xxx ";
            $message = "text";

            $headers  = "From: xxx<xxx@xxx.xx>\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
            $mailheader .= "Return-Path: failuremail@" .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. "\r\n";
            $mailheader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $mailheader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
            $mailheader .= "Message-ID: <" .time(). " noreply@" .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. ">\r\n";
            $mailheader .= "X-Mailer: PHP v" .phpversion(). "\r\n\r\n";

            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

            }//**

            }else{

                $output[$fileBase] = "Fehler beim Upload des Bildmaterials!";
                $errors2[$fileBase][] = "Fehler: Die hochgeladenen Dateien können nicht verschoben werden!";
            }//             
        }//

        if (count($errors) > 0) {
            die("Failurecode: ");
            echo "$errors";
    }...
```

and i would like to approach to get the error messages from the 2 dimensional array the same way like i get them from my other error messages that comes from one dimensional arrays at the same page as  the formular will be. in case of "die" it will open a new empty page to show the error. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need two loops for this, but the approach you have taken is slightly flawed. You need a validation loop which performs all the validation for all the files, then a second loop which just moves the files to permanent storage.

Something like this (**FIXED**):

```
<?php

  // Settings
  $allowedExtensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'tiff', 'gif');
  $maxSize = 2097152;
  $storageDir = 'a/b/c/tmp_images';

  // Result arrays
  $errors = $output = array();

  if (!empty($_FILES['image'])){  

    // Validation loop (I prefer for loops for this specific task)
    for ($i = 0; isset($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]); $i++) {

      $fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
      $fileSize = $_FILES['image']['size'][$i];
      $fileErr = $_FILES['image']['error'][$i];
      $fileExt = strtolower(pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

      // Validate extension
      if (!in_array($fileExt, $allowedExtensions)) {
        $errors[$fileName][] = "Format $fileExt in image $fileName is not accepted";
      }

      // Validate size
      if ($fileSize > $maxSize) {
        $errors[$fileName][] = "$fileName excedes the maximum file size of $maxSize bytes";
      }

      // Check errors
      if ($fileErr) {
        $errors[$fileName][] = "$fileName uploaded with error code $fileErr";
      }

    }

    // Handle validation errors here
    if (count($errors) > 0) {
      die("Errors validating uploads: ".print_r($errors, TRUE));
    }

    // Create the storage directory if it doesn't exist
    if (!is_dir($storageDir)) {
      if (!mkdir($storageDir, 0755, TRUE)) { // Passing TRUE as the third argument creates recursively
        die("Unable to create storage directory $storageDir");
      }
    }

    // File move loop
    for ($i = 0; isset($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]); $i++) {

      // Get base info
      $fileBase = basename($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]);
      $fileName = pathinfo($fileBase, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
      $fileExt = pathinfo($fileBase, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      $fileTmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i];

      // Construct destination path
      $fileDst = $storageDir.'/'.basename($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]);
      for ($j = 0; file_exists($fileDst); $j++) {
        $fileDst = "$storageDir/$fileName-$j.$fileExt";
      }

      // Move the file    
      if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, $fileDst)) {
        $output[$fileBase] = "Stored $fileBase OK";
      } else {
        $output[$fileBase] = "Failure while uploading $fileBase!";
        $errors[$fileBase][] = "Failure: Can't move uploaded file $fileBase!";
      }

    }

    // Handle file move errors here
    if (count($errors) > 0) {
      die("Errors moving uploaded files: ".print_r($errors, TRUE));
    }

  }
```

Comment: this seems to be the right way. i'm still testing it out. there are some small mistakes in here. i will comment later on. for the moment i like to thank you for your help. please have a watch on this question. i will give further information and feedback today in the evening.

Comment: okay, sorry for my lateness. here my feedback: this code seems to have problems in case of two different file types. it seems like if (count($errors)>0){die ("Df..."}

Comment: please show the output of `print_r($errors)` when you get a failure

Comment: i'm sorry for this comment. this should not have been posted. i updated my question to give further information.

Comment: hello, i got to the point that this is nearly working how it should do. it seems like it is running wrong with that part: // Construct destination path
   $fileDst = $storageDir.'/'.basename($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]);
   for ($j = 0; file_exists($fileDst); $j++) {
    $fileDst = "$storageDir/$fileName-$j.$fileExt"; because i can only upload one file in case of two or more accepted endings. i will get the error message: Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to access abc1.png in /a/b/build.php on line 216 for each file without the first one.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$filename = $_FILES["quoteexcel"]["name"]; 
//here $filename is an array of file names to be uploaded
$tmpvalues = $_FILES["quoteexcel"]["tmp_name"]; 
//here $tmpvalues is an array of temporary file names

$j=0;
foreach($filename as $key => $value)
{
 $ext = pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);       
 if($ext=='jpg' || $ext=='jpeg' || $ext=='png' || $ext=='tiff' || $ext=='gif')
 $j = $j;
 else     $j++;                                         
}

if($j==0)
{
 foreach($filename as $key => $value)
  {
     //do the upload process here;
  }
}
else
{
   echo "file format not supported";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))
{  
    foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $key => $array_value)
    {
        $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'][$key];
        $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key];

        $file_extension = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $file_extension = strtolower($file_extension);          

        if($file_size > 2097152)
        {
            $errors[$file_name][] = "maxsize of 2MB on $file_name has reached";
        }           
        if(!in_array($file_extension, $allowed_extension)
        {
            $errors[$file_name][] = "format $file_extension in image $file_name is not accepted";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you simply left the main content of this script. this is definetly not the right way to solve the problem. sorry.